# Are there increasing returns for multi-consuming leaves in the skill tree

Tags: salt-and-sanctuary

There are skills in SaS titled 'Fortified Strength', and 'Bolstered Dexterity'. There are many instances of these skills, and each appears capable of consuming 3 skill points each. Is there an advantage to dumping more than one skill point into a leaf of this type or is there no point in the depth vs breadth approach to the tree?

There are no respecs in this game asfaik, so that's why I'm asking.

Answer (score 1):

There is no increased returns as far as I can tell from testing it out myself. Each new rank into a single leaf yields only one point of str, dex, wisdom, etc...

Answer (score 1):

No there are no increasing returns. 
But it realy makes sense to put more points into 1 skill, because u need to have efficient base stats to manage the HighClass Weapons. 
Like Heavy Armor 5: you need to be able to lift the stuff and you need enough stamina to even jump or run. So if you dont put enough skill points into the slots on the way to Armor 5 it becomes usless to lern it.